# Environment.ProcessorCount in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure

Let's say I have [A3](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/) and in my code which is executed at Windows Azure I write

```
int numberOfProcessors = Environment.ProcessorCount;
```

What will go into numberOfProcessors variable? I assume that numberOfProcessors  will be equal to zero because [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount(v=vs.100).aspx) claims that Windows Azure doesn't belong to supported platforms for that function. If I'm correct, then what can I use as replacement Environment.ProcessorCount?

Comment: The link you provided doesn't have that claim. The platform is related to the Guest OS of the VM.

Comment: try it and find out!

Comment: `NumberOfCores` and `ProcessorCount` are different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you've read the wrong MSDN :) There is no such information in it about azure. Moreover, there is a lot of articles for `ProcessorCount`usage in `Azure` environment:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // Show the Environment Information
    builder.AppendLine("<h2>Environment Information</h2>");
    builder.Append("<b>Machine Name: </b>" + Environment.MachineName + "<br>");
    builder.Append("<b>OS Version: </b>" + Environment.OSVersion + "<br>");
    builder.Append("<b>Is 64Bit Operating System: </b>" + Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem + "<br>");
    builder.Append("<b>Processor Count: </b>" + Environment.ProcessorCount + "<br>");
    builder.Append("<b>User Name: </b>" + Environment.UserName + "<br>");
    builder.Append("<b>Is Debugger Attached: </b>" + Debugger.IsAttached + "<br>");

    // Show the Process Information
    builder.AppendLine("<h2>Processes Information</h2>");
    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
        builder.AppendLine(process.ProcessName + "</br>");

    // Show the RoleEnvironment Information
    builder.AppendLine("<h2>Role Environment Information</h2>");
    builder.Append("<b>Curent Role Instance Name: </b>" + RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name + "<br>");
    builder.Append("<b>Deployment Id: </b>" + RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId + "<br>");
    builder.Append("<b>Is Emulated: </b>" + RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated + "<br>");

    // Display the Resutls
    InfoLabel.Text = builder.ToString();
}
```

and result for it:

[image]

from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/windows-azure-viewing-deployment-machine-details/). So, it definitely work in Azure `WebRole`.

But if you are talking about the `NumberOfCores`, then you have to change it manually - it is [administrative function](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/04/azure-limits-quotas-increase-requests/):

[image]